# Не работает #include virtual в php

Tags: debian, apache2

В браузере при загрузке страницы строки вида

```
<!--#include virtual="/index/ssi/news" --> 
<!--#include virtual="/design/ssi/right_top" -->
```

и др. отображаются в браузере комментариями, вместо них должна появляться разметка, находящаяся в других файлах

В проекте написан класс (DefaultRoute), который по запросу находит необходимый класс GET.php,
если ввели localhost/users - то найдёт файл users/GET.php, который в свою очередь формирует параметры для файла разметки - users/users.html.php

Итого: есть DefaultRoute, который по запросу определяет необходимый контроллер GET.php, контроллер в свою очередь формирует необходимые параметры для разметки users.html.php
Вероятно, что  и путь до папки "/index/ssi/news" связаны с вышеуказанной схемой работы приложения, но вот нигде нет и упоминания #include virtual, где бы в ручную всё обрабатывалось.

Конфигурация - apache2, debian, php7

В чем может быть проблема и как её исправить?

PS - всё таки похоже дело в ssi, но я никак не могу его настроить.

PS_PS: включил ssi - теперь apache2 что-то пытается сделать со строками вида 
, но безуспешно и выдаёт ошибки :

1)Fatal error: Cannot declare class Имя_Класса, because the name is already in use in ...
2)Notice: Constant Имя_Константы already defined in ...
Притом все константы определены в config.php (define('LC_LANGUAGE_LIST', []);), который используется только при запуске приложения в app.php:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/config.php';
(new Application()->run()->send());
```

Чего-то не хватает в настройках ssi

PS_PS_PS: Исправил fatal ошибки - теперь ssi как будто бы зацикливается и в итоге ошибка:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator at postmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

Comment: включите модуль для ssi: `$ sudo a2enmod include`

Comment: Выполнил `sudo a2enmod include` и `service apache2 restart` - ситуация не исправилась

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная проблема была в том, что браузер не определял директивы вида 
`<!--#include virtual="/index/ssi/news" -->` - как стало известно, надо смотреть в сторону ssi (server side include). В nginx включение выполняется так - `ssi on;` (см. ример кода ниже)

Таким образом проблема после подключения ssi вылилась в следующую:
Есть страница /a. В ней через ssi подключаеться /b. php получает на обработку не /b, а /a в REQUEST_URI и отдает снова /a, в которой подзапрос /b и так рекурсивно пока что-то не отвалиться толи nginx, толи клиент

Решение:
для правильной работы ssi в nginx для fastcgi нужно устанавливать параметр

```
fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $uri;
```

иначе он будет передавать на обработчик URI базового запроса, а не подзапроса

Также сменил apache на nginx и добавил в nginx.conf строки, которые устраняют зацикливание:

```
http {
    ...
    server {
        ...
        ssi on;
        location / {
            ...
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
        }
    }
```